# Updating MarkLogic License

Tags: marklogic

I am attempting to update licenses for our hosts.  I get a an error "URI /admin/v1/init does not exist."

I am assuming this is a configuration issue on our part but cannot find any resources to tell me what those may be.

Comment: I think the uri would normally read /v1/init (without /admin in front). There may be some url rewriting and proxying going on. I recommend reaching out to MarkLogic Support, so they can help guide you through as it will be difficult to make suggestions without knowing specifics.

Comment: thanks Mads for the input.  i will put in a support ticket.